# Where can I get such a UI component plugin?

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

The image below shows a input component from Facebook that helps in building a list of people from a suggested list.

How do I build such a input component using primefaces or JSF components or can I get it ready from somewhere else ?

[image: Facebook share filter]

Looking to support IE6 and above if possible.

Comment: What browsers do you need to support? IE6? IE7? IE8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a much nicer solution to this through [fpsFBMSelect](http://code.google.com/p/fpsfbmselect/)(a multiselect control based on jQuery)

See the demo [here](http://nukedukem.orgfree.com/fpsfbmselect/)

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is the jqueryui suite's autocomplete: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: Yeah. @Marcos: Combined with a div you add spans to when the user chooses items (with the x so they can be removed). Should be fairly straight-forward using this autocompleter.